# How to setup proxy in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, proxy

I have just started using iOS technologies, and developing an iPhone application using Swift.
I am trying to query server using following code:

```
var url = NSURL(string: "http://someurl:8080/?type=Refresh")
var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
var connection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)
```

But I need to setup proxy on my iPhone device if I need to query that server.
So now I want to setup http proxy (server and port) in Swift code itself.

I looked into [CFProxySupport Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFProxySupport/index.html) by Apple, but not understanding how can I use it.
I have written following code till now:

```
var proxy_server: CFString = “proxy” // proxy server
var proxy_port: CFNumber = 8080 // port

var keys: [CFStringRef] = [kCFProxyTypeKey, kCFProxyHostNameKey, kCFProxyPortNumberKey]
var values: [CFTypeRef] = [kCFProxyTypeHTTP, proxy_server, proxy_port]

var proxy_dict: CFDictionary = CFDictionaryCreate(
    kCFAllocatorDefault,
    UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<Void>>(keys),
    UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<Void>>(values),
    3,
    nil,
    nil)

var proxies: Unmanaged<CFArray> = CFNetworkCopyProxiesForURL(NSURL(string: "http://someurl:8080"), proxy_dict)
```

Can anyone please tell me how to use `proxies` to setup proxy?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `CFProxySupport` framework allows your app to retrieve proxies that have been configured in the device.  Some of these proxy configurations may actually be a auto proxy config URL/script - so `CFNetworkCopyProxiesForURL` may evaluate these scripts to the determine the proxies that apply to the specified URL.

`CFProxySupport` does not allow you to configure the proxies that the device will use.  Further, `NSURLConnection` doesn't honour the device proxy settings.  You can use the code you have to retrieve the configured proxy and then use this with a library, such as NSURLSession or AFNetworking, that does support the use of a proxy server.  In NSURLSession you specify the proxy configuration in the `connectionProxy` dictionary of the [NSURLSessionConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSessionConfiguration/connectionProxyDictionary) object

Comment: Where is this framework now? Was it renamed or removed by Apple?

Comment: It looks like it has been retired.

Comment: Do you know any replacement for it?